# How to transform text categories into ones and zeros vector in Python for classification?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm preparing data for multilabel classification and I want to transform text categories into zeros/ones vector.

Example input (dataframe):

```
['a']
['b']
['e', 'd']
['a', 'g', 'x']
```

etc.
example output:

```
[1 0 0 0 0 0 0 ... 0]
[0 1 0 0 0 0 0 ... 0]
[0 0 0 1 1 0 0 ... 0]
[1 0 0 0 0 0 1 ... 0]
```

etc.

There's 200 categories.
I haven't found how to do it when you have to deal with multilabel classification.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Try using a combination of `pd.get_dummies` (*designed* for one-hot-encoding) and `explode` + `groupby(level=0)`:`

```
out = pd.get_dummies(df['a'].explode()).groupby(level=0).sum()
```

Output:

```
>>> out
   a  b  d  e  g  x
0  1  0  0  0  0  0
1  0  1  0  0  0  0
2  0  0  1  1  0  0
3  1  0  0  0  1  1
```

Or a little shorter:

```
out = df['a'].str.join(',').str.get_dummies(',')
```

Output:

```
>>> out
   a  b  d  e  g  x
0  1  0  0  0  0  0
1  0  1  0  0  0  0
2  0  0  1  1  0  0
3  1  0  0  0  1  1
```

Then...

```
df['class'] = out.to_numpy().tolist()
```

Output:

```
>>> df
           a               class
0        [a]  [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
1        [b]  [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
2     [e, d]  [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0]
3  [a, g, x]  [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1]
```

Comment: But that will generate a lot of new columns, right? What I wanna do instead is one column with huge vector

Comment: @appendix check the answer now. I added more options.

Comment: @appendix updated again. Please check now - it should be exactly what you want :)

Comment: Nice one  ~ :-) .

Comment: Thank you @BENY! Yours is really cool too.

Answer (score 1):

Let us just try `MultiLabelBinarizer` from `sklearn`

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import MultiLabelBinarizer

mlb = MultiLabelBinarizer()
 
s = mlb.fit_transform(df['a'])
s
Out[239]: 
array([[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1]])
```